# Android:ListView in PopupWindow cannot be selected

Tags: android, listview, popupwindow

I set the layout which has a **listview** to a **popupwindow**,and then I set the `popupwindow.setFocusale(false);`,and add `"android:focusable="true""` attribute to **listview**,
after that I click the **listview** in the **popupwindow** ,the **item in listview** cannot be selected,
can anyone tell the solution?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of items do you have in your listview?
Look at that : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414&can=1&q=listview&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars
Moreover,  try to play  with setClickable on your listview.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The question is not that it cannot be selected, it just doesn't show until the ListView is scrolled. It is selected indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and in my case `PopupWindow.setFocusble(false)` was required (and using `ListPopupWindow` was not a solution in my case as a lot of stuff in the project already used base `PopupWindow`'s functionality including extending).

If someone in the same situation there is a kind of workaround based on bug discusson [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414) (post #9)

The main idea is that `ListView`'s hierarchy is still receives touch events so we can manually trigger `onItemClick()`.

However this approach is not 100% identical to real `ListView`'s touch handling (like there is no glow of selection while tapping a row) this done pretty well for me for the moment.

If someone has more precise solution of this problem, please share.

So, here is complete `Adapter`'s code which can be used with `ListView` inside `PopupWindow` which is `setFocusable(false)`:

private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ListView mOwningListView;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<String> objects, ListView listView) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, objects);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mOwningListView = listView;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.font_pick_row, null);
    }
    // this is the key point of workaround
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*
             *  as every row is still receiving their touches
             *  we can use this to manually trigger onItemClick
             *  since it doesn't firing in popupWindow.setFocusable(false)  
             */
            mOwningListView.getOnItemClickListener().onItemClick(mOwningListView, v, position, getItemId(position));

        }
    });
    //... other stuff
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

why are u making popupwindow focus false..does it affect your UI if it left focussable.i guess thats the reason ListView is not getting focus.

Comment: yeah,I know the popupwindow's focus effects the listview.I set it to false cause I wanna override the popupwindow's "setTouchInterceptor(...){...MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE//For this attr,I have to set focusable false...}"

Comment: i am not getting you here..is there any relationship between set focus=false and using setTouchInterceptor() if yes then I m sorry I am not getting that care to explain..it will be good if you can post some code so that we can try it out and see where the problem lies.